# Erlang: Forced to make method public, why?

Tags: erlang

I am following Joe Armstrong's book `Programming Erlang, 2nd Edition`, where we make a file server.

My code:

```
-module(afile_server).
-author("harith").

%% API
-export([start/1]).

start(Dir) ->  spawn(afile_server, loop, [Dir]).

loop(Dir) ->
    receive
        {Client, list_dir}  ->
            Client ! {self(), file:list_dir(Dir)};
        {Client, {get_file, File}}  ->
            File_Path = filename:join(Dir, File),
            Client ! {self(), file:read_file(File_Path)}
    end,
    loop(Dir).
```

As we can see, `loop` is a private method and should not be exposed to the outside world. Now when I run this, I get:

```
1> FileServer = afile_server:start(".").
<0.33.0>

=ERROR REPORT==== 3-Jan-2015::06:58:56 ===
Error in process <0.33.0> with exit value: {undef,[{afile_server,loop,["."],[]}]}

2>
```

But when I make `loop` public as:

```
-module(afile_server).
-author("harith").

%% API
-export([start/1, loop/1]).

start(Dir) ->  spawn(afile_server, loop, [Dir]).

loop(Dir) ->
    receive
        {Client, list_dir}  ->
            Client ! {self(), file:list_dir(Dir)};
        {Client, {get_file, File}}  ->
            File_Path = filename:join(Dir, File),
            Client ! {self(), file:read_file(File_Path)}
    end,
    loop(Dir).
```

then it runs fine:

```
1> FileServer = afile_server:start(".").
<0.33.0>
2>
```

Does `spawn` required the method to be public? I guess yes because it runs it as:

```
afile_server:loop(Dir)
```

but I want to make sure there is nothing else wrong.

Comment: Just a note on terminology: they are *functions*, not *methods*, and functions are either *exported* or not, rather than *public* or *private*.

Comment: Adding to Steve's comment, when I hear "method" in reference to Erlang, it means the same as "technique". Consider that in "By what method should I do X?", "What approach should I take to Z?", and "What is the preferred technique for Q?" come across as extremely similar semantic uses of "method", "approach" and "technique". I think only in Java does the term "method" have such a distinct technical meaning (though its understood and used in other  Java-esque OOP settings/langs). "Function" and "process" have distinct meanings in reference to Erlang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use spawn with M:F:A you are forced to set loop public.

You can avoid it in this way:

```
-module(afile_server).
-export([start/1]).

start(Dir) ->  spawn(fun() -> loop(Dir) end).

loop(Dir) ->
    receive
        {Client, list_dir}  ->
            Client ! {self(), file:list_dir(Dir)};
        {Client, {get_file, File}}  ->
            File_Path = filename:join(Dir, File),
            Client ! {self(), file:read_file(File_Path)}
    end,
    loop(Dir).
```

If your methods don't have arguments you can also use:

```
spawn(fun loop/0),
```

A good reason to use the version with M:F:A consists in the fact that whenever you load a new version of the same module this new version will be called. Otherwise you will keep on calling the old module.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason to for having the function exported, even if it is in the same module, is that with `spawn` you create a completely new context and environment so it is reasonable to have to call an exported function.